# How to sum the corresponding values in the List into a Tuple?

Tags: scala

I have a list details of this type :

```
case class Detail(point: List[Double], cluster: Int)

val details = List(Detail(List(2.0, 10.0),1), Detail(List(2.0, 5.0),3),
                   Detail(List(8.0,  4.0),2), Detail(List(5.0, 8.0),2))
```

I want filter this list into a tuple which contains a sum of each corresponding point where the cluster is 2

So I filter this List :

```
details.filter(detail => detail.cluster == 2)
```

which returns :

```
List(Detail(List(8.0, 4.0),2), Detail(List(5.0, 8.0),2))
```

It's the summing of the corresponding values I'm having trouble with. In this example the tuple should contain (8+5, 4+8) = (13, 12)

I'm thinking to flatten the List and then sum each corresponding value but

```
List(details).flatten
```

just returns the same List

How to sum the corresponding values in the List into a Tuple ?

I could achieve this easily using a for loop and just extract the details I need into a counter but what is the functional solution ?

Comment: I think you mean 4 + 8 = 12

Comment: @0__ +1 thanks, question updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you want to happen if the lists for different `Detail`s have different lengths? 
Or same length which is different from 2? Tuples are generally only used when you need a fixed in advance number of elements; you won't even be able to write a return type if you need tuples of different lengths.

Assuming that all of them are lists of the same length and you get a list in return, something like this should work (untested):

```
details.filter(_.cluster == 2).map(_.point).transpose.map(_.sum)
```

I.e. first get all `point`s as a list of lists, transpose it so you get a list for each "coordinate", and sum each of these lists.

If you do know that each point has two coordinates, this should likely be reflected in your `Point` type, by using `(Double, Double)` instead of `List[Double]` and you can just fold over the list of points, which should be a bit more efficient. Look at definition of `foldLeft` and the standard implementation of `sum` in terms of `foldLeft`:

```
def sum(list: List[Int]): Int = list.foldLeft(0)((acc, x) => acc + x)
```

and it should be easy to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one foldLeft with PF without filter:

```
  details.foldLeft((0.0,0.0))({
    case ((accX, accY), Detail(x :: y :: Nil, 2)) => (accX + x, accY + y)
    case (acc, _) => acc
  })

  res1: (Double, Double) = (13.0,12.0)
```